# Use java in matlab

Tags: java, matlab, classpath

I encountered a problem when I tried to use java from matlab. I read through the tutorials from MathWork.com several times, also I re-installed the JDK1.6, in order to be compatible with matlab. However, after my work, it still doesn't work...

Here is the contents in classpath.txt:

```
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\java\jarext\xstream.jar                                  
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\win64   \javabuilder.jar            

    DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

C:\Users\Gao\Desktop\connected_components_labeling
```

Clearly, the directory is included in the file. 
The connected_component_labeling is just a folder on my disk. The classes that I want to use in the connected_components_labeling are: Disjoint_Set.class and Node.class    are in the connected_components_labeling folder.

I tried:

```
x =  Disjoint_Set();
```

also

```
x = connected_components_labeling.Disjoint_Set();
```

None of them work. The only feedback I got from matlab is:

```
??? Undefined variable "connected_components_labeling" or class
"connected_components_labeling.Disjoint_Set".
```

I'm pretty frustrated. Could anyone help me out? I'd appreciate it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is "connected_components_labeling" a package? Are the classes in a jar file? Or are they simply .class files sitting in that directory? Were those classes perhaps already in a package and then removed from it?

Comment: I just edited it. The connected_components_labeling is a package. The classes are not in a jar file. They are just .class files.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If connected_components_labeling is actually a package, it shouldn't be listed on the path. The directory that it lives in should be on the path instead. So the Desktop directory here. Probably not a great place for it.

Comment: @Gao: You should use `javaaddpath` to add entries to the Java class path

Comment: @Amro: I tried javaaddpath(). This function will add the files to dynamic path. And it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are compiling the java files using a JRE/JDK that MATLAB is compatible with. As far as I can tell, MATLAB does not work properly with Java 7, so stick with Java 6 for the moment...

There are a couple of environment variables that affect MATLAB. In my case I have:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
MATLAB_JAVA = C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
PATH = ...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin
```

Here is a simple test I just did:

#### C:\work\Student.java

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    public Student(String str) {
        name = str;
    }
    public void setName(String str) {
        name = str;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student s = new Student("amro");
        s.setName("unknown");
        System.out.println("Hello " + s.getName());
    }
}
```

I compile: `javac Student.java` (the output is placed in the same directory `c:\work\Student.class`). Now I test it from MATLAB:

```
javaaddpath('C:\work')

javaMethod('main','Student','')

s = Student('me')
char( s.getName() )
```

I get:

```
Hello unknown

s =
Student@8d6877

ans =
me
```

Comment: +1 for checking that your JDK version is compatible with your MATLAB version. Fixed my problem. Thanks! Here's a [list of supported JDK versions for each MATLAB version](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html) (click on the "Supported Compilers" link).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: From what I understand there are [workarounds](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-java-7-in-matlab-r2013a-and-earlier/).. But you don't have to worry about that anymore, you'll be happy to know that MATLAB R2013b finally upgraded to Java 7.