# Matlab-Java interface, conflicting Java versions

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I used the Matlab deployment tool to build a matlab code into a java project. I am having some problem with the Matlab-Java interface, the error while running the java code is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to
>   find the library mclmcrrt7_15.dll, required by MATLAB Builder JA, on
>   java.library.path. This library is typically installed along with
>   MATLAB or the MCR, its absence may indicate an issue with that
>   installation or the current path configuration.The MCR version that
>   this component is trying to use is: 7.15.

When I type "version -java" in the Matlab console, the answer is Java 1.6.0_17-b04. So,I changed my Path in the system settings to ...\Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin But since I have Java version-7 installed, It is not using version-6. In command prompt, when I checked the version of java and javac, I saw that the version of javac is 1.6 but that of java is 1.7. I also made a CLASSPATH environment variable and a JAVAHOME variable and set it to 1.6. Could you please tell me how do I change the java version being used by the system to 1.6 so that matlab can interact with it?

I think this is the problem, but I am just guessing from the error message. Please let me know if the problem is something else, and not just the incompatibility in java versions.

Comment: Referring to [Thread Subject: MCR on Windows 7 64bit - help!](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/313854)I might guess you need to install the MCR that complies with the deployment tool.

Comment: @user1493972: read first part of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11056140/97160

Answer (score 0):

Is the DLL `mclmcrrt7_15.dll` on the `PATH` anywhere?

For Java to be able to load a DLL, the DLL needs to be in a folder listed in the `java.library.path` system property.  The default value for this property on Windows is the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The DLL mclmcrrt7_15.dll was originally in the folder C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\runtime\win64

Comment: but I copied it to the PATH folder. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: Why have you copied the DLL to a folder already on the `PATH` instead of adding the folder containing the DLL to the `PATH`???  Maybe this DLL is trying to look for other DLLs in this folder and is failing to load because it can't find them?

Comment: Okay, my bad. Now I added the folder containing the DLL to the PATH. It still is giving the same error..

Comment: Have you restarted MATLAB since you changed the PATH?  (I admit I've not actually used MATLAB and Java together, and I don't have access to a MATLAB installation at the moment but I have worked with Java and external DLLs before.  I also admit I'm running out of ideas about how to fix your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the same error on my machine.
In my case, it is fixed by add the `MATLAB` path into the `SYSTEM` environment variables:

add in `PATH`

```
-C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;
-C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win64
```

Wish it is helpful.